# Special database creation - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a school project and i hit a small snag . I just learned some basic mysql and i can work with single tables/row such as register users , validating logins and outputting all the data in a table.

I now have a more complex issue and i'm not very sure how to proceed .

I need to create a 'courses' that have several subsections such as :

(1) A course can have different lectures for each semester

(2) A lecture has its specific tutorials & labs ( more than one )

I know how to create a single row such as : username , frst name , last name , email etc....

But for the stucture below - i'm not really sure how to do this. I don't have a pre-existing code yet as i have not yet decided how to proceed .

i'm thinking about adding more than one data in the fields like : sections ="TA,TB" but i read that its not recommended in mysql

[image: course]
<sub>(source: [4.ii.gl](http://4.ii.gl/JPvJK-.png))</sub>

[image: course2]
<sub>(source: [2.ii.gl](http://2.ii.gl/sf9Smu.png))</sub>

Comment: recommended read - to be able to create tables, not just rows. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html 

what your project requires is multiple tables, related to each other with constraints. Constraints basically are rules saying what the relationship entails. There's a lot here... but without that knowledge, I don't see how you can complete this task correctly

Answer (score 1):

You schould make multiple tables.

One for courses. One for lectures and one for tutorials etc.

Then you bind them togheter woth unique IDs